# Арифметическая прогрессия задана первым членом A и разностью D

Tags: java

Задание. Арифметическая прогрессия задана первым членом A и разностью D. Составить
программу вывода на экран дисплея всех положительных членов прогрессии.
не очень понимаю как это реализовать в коде

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что делать, если разность положительна? Нужных членов будет бесконечное количество

Comment: @MBo, при использовании стандартного `int` или даже `long` для представления членов прогрессии их количество будет не такое уж и бесконечное.

Answer (score 0):

**Решил самостоятельно не уверен что всё правильно**

```
public class VARIAN_3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int a = (-3);
    int d = 3;
    int[] massive = new int[20];
    massive [i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; massive.length > i ; i++) {
        s = a + d * (i-1);
       // i = i + 1;
        //a = a - d;
        if(massive[i] == 0 && s > 0){
            massive[i] = s;
        }

    }
    for (int l: massive){
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

}

`